# replace regular expression in sublime text

Tags: regex, replace, sublimetext2

I have application where few labels are written like

```
ui-label-Display Not Masked
```

Now I want to replace it by

```
ui-label-Display_Not_Masked
```

so i have written search regex by

```
ui-label-(\w+ )*
```

This searches all expression but I am not able to create a expression to replace this text as required.
I have written one regex

```
$1_
```

which replaces

```
ui-label-Display Not Masked
```

by

```
ui-label-Display Not_Masked
```

Comment: will it always be three words?

Comment: No. It can be one or more than one after ui-label-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot be done with a single regex in a single iteration.
You have two choices:

1. Replace `(ui-label-\w+)` (note the space at the end) with `$1_` until it no longer matches anything.
2. Make a looong regex with as many capture groups as necessary, i.e. `(ui-label-\w+) (?:(\w+)(?: (\w+))?)?` and replace with `$1_$2_$3`.

Comment: Second regex cannot find more than 3 string in "ui-label-a b c d e f ....".
Can't we make one generic regex to find all such string and one to replace all strings? 
Actually my problem is that I have one web app where i have labels by format ui-label-a b c.... And now I have to replace them by ui-label-a_b_c.... 
So i am little unsure to write such regex.

Comment: @ShubhamParamhans: Like I said before, you either have to replace one space at a time, or make an appropriately long regex.

Comment: What do you think is better writing one sublime regex to find and replace or one python script to replace the matching pattern in file?

Comment: I don't think writing a script is worth the effort. Hit `Ctrl+H`, enter the regex, and press `replace all` a couple of times...